# Modify the html by using jquery css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the html code like this:

```
<table class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">1<input class="text social" type="text" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">2 <input class="text social" type="text"/></td>                             
    </tr>       
</table>
```

What I need I want it to be like this:

```
 <table class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">1</td>
        <td><input class="text social" type="text" /></td>                                  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">2</td>
        <td><input class="text social" type="text"/></td>   
    </tr>   
</table>
```

I'm stuck with this, anyone help me please,Thanks.

Comment: What help do you want exactly. Cause we are a bit confused

Comment: You already have the second code. then where is the issue? Do you want to generate dynamically ?

Comment: Make your self clear what you want so we can also get clear and can help you quickly

Comment: yes sure I want it generate dynamique when load page.

Comment: "What have you tried?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var $table = $('table').clone();
$table.html('');
$('td').each(function () {
    var $tr = $('<tr/>').html($('<td/>').html($(this).text()));
    $tr.append($('<td/>').html($(this).find('input').clone()));
    $table.append($tr);
});
$('table').remove();
$table.appendTo('body');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SFmnB/)

Answer (score 0):

> *"Modify the html by using jquery css"*

I don't know what you mean by "using jquery css", but here's one way to do it using jQuery methods:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $table = $(".tbl"),
        $newTR = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo($table);
    $newTR.append($table.find("td").last());
    $table.find("tr").each(function() {
        $("<td></td>").append($(this).find("input")).appendTo(this);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NWZGV/

Comment: it works for only one line,I mean only `<tr></tr>` if I add many `<tr></tr>`,It is not work well. Thanks

Comment: Well it works _for the input and output shown in your question._ The question didn't mention anything about additional rows in the input, so given that your output requires creating rows you'd need to specify whether they get added between existing rows or at the end. In any case you should be able to use my answer as a starting point and complete your (previously unstated) requirement yourself. Or just use @RohanKumar's answer, I think it'll probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.text social').insertBefore('</td><td>');
$('td[colspan='2']').first().insertAfter('</td><td>');
```

Comment: That looks very neat, but it doesn't actually work. `.insertBefore()` doesn't amend the page's html as a string, it inserts things into the DOM...

Comment: `$('.text social').before('</td><td>');
$('td[colspan='2']').first().after('</td><td>');`
This should work, if you have a loaded html file and you want to modify it

Comment: No, that has the same problem. `.before()` and `.after()` insert content/elements into the DOM, not into a string of html. Please give it a try for yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SacTP/) and you'll see that passing the string `'</td><td>'` to `.before()` actually crashes jQuery (a syntax error appears in the console).

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yu3GR/)**

you can change html using jquery

**HTML:**

```
<table class="tbl" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">1<input class="text social" type="text" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">2<input class="text social" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" value="change" id="btn" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        var s = "<tr>"
            + "<td colspan='2'>1</td>"
            + "<td><input class='text social' type='text' /></td>"  
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td colspan='2'>2</td>"
            + "<td><input class='text social' type='text' /></td>"   
            + "</tr>";
        $('table').html('');
        $('table').append(s);
    });
});
```